# Get n rows before specific value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

Say, i have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'val':[3.2, 2.4, -2.3, -4.9, 3.2, 2.4, -2.3, -4.9, 2.4, -2.3, -4.9], 
        'label': [0, 2, 1, -1, 1, 2, -1, -1,1, 1, -1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
df
     val    label
0    3.2     0
1    2.4     2
2   -2.3     1
3   -4.9    -1
4    3.2     1
5    2.4     2
6   -2.3    -1
7   -4.9    -1
8    2.4     1
9   -2.3     1
10  -4.9    -1
```

I want to take each n (for example 2) rows before -1 value in column label. In the given df first -1 appears at index 3, we take 2 rows before it and drop index 3, then next -1 appears at index 6, we again keep 2 rows before and etc. The desired output is as following:

```
    val     label
1    2.4     2
2   -2.3     1
4    3.2     1
5    2.4     2
6   -2.3    -1
8    2.4     1
9   -2.3     1
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Do you want to do it in a vectorized manner, or would a loop be enough?

Comment: loop should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `index` values and then get the previous two row index values:

```py
idx = df[df.label == -1].index
filtered_idx = (idx-1).union(idx-2)
filtered_idx = filtered_idx[filtered_idx > 0]

df_new = df.iloc[filtered_idx]
```

output:

```
   val  label
1  2.4      2
2 -2.3      1
4  3.2      1
5  2.4      2
6 -2.3     -1
8  2.4      1
9 -2.3      1
```

Speed comparison with for a `for loop` solution:

```py
# create large df:
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((20000000,2)), columns=["val","label"])
df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.01).index, "label"] = - 1

def vectorized_filter(df):
    idx = df[df.label == -1].index
    filtered_idx = (idx -1).union(idx-2)
    df_new = df.iloc[filtered_idx]
    return df_new

def loop_filter(df):
    filter = df.loc[df['label'] == -1].index
    req_idx = []
    for idx in filter:
        if idx == 0:
            continue
        elif idx == 1:
            req_idx.append(idx-1)
        else:
            req_idx.append(idx-2)
            req_idx.append(idx-1)    
    req_idx = list(set(req_idx))
    df2 = df.loc[df.index.isin(req_idx)]
    return df2

%timeit vectorized_filter(df)
%timeit loop_filter(df)

vectorized runs ~20x faster on my machine
```

Comment: thanks for answer. what does (idx -1).union(idx-2) part do? idx-2 takes two rows before the label is -1, mainly i did not understand why (idx -1)

Comment: @Sascha idx == Int64Index([3, 6, 7, 10], dtype='int64'), idx - 1 == Int64Index([2, 5, 6, 9], dtype='int64').  It just offsets row values by -1, the combines (in set sense) with idx offset by -2.

Comment: Also: see the speed comparison for why looping is a bad idea.  It's ok for small dfs, but you will find it's not fast enough for large data quickly

Comment: @Sascha `idx` represents the indices of `-1`. `idx-1` represent indices just before `-1`, similarly `idx-2` represents indices before `-1` by an offset of 2. `union` here is same as in sets it combines both of them `(idx-1).union(idx-2)` will give you indices before `-1` by an offset `1` and `2`. :) Here's a link to relevant documenation page [`pd.Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html)

Comment: @anon01 `pd.Index.union` by default gives the sorted output. So, `df.iloc[filtered_idx]` is same as `df.iloc[filtered_idx].sort_index()`, `sort_index` is redundant here.

Comment: It means, if i want to take 3 or 4 rows before specific value, the code should look like: (idx -1).union(idx-2).union(idx-3)?

Comment: @Sascha yes.  You can examine the output in jupyter or ipython to see the index values.  For more than two rows there may be a more concise way.  Also noticed I fixed a bug where the index will wrap negative just now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
markers = df[df.label.eq(-1)].index
for marker in markers: 
    new_df = new_df.append(df[marker-2:marker])

new_df.reset_index().drop_duplicates().set_index("index")
```

Result:

```
       val  label
index            
1      2.4      2
2     -2.3      1
4      3.2      1
5      2.4      2
6     -2.3     -1
8      2.4      1
9     -2.3      1
```

Comment: I think this will repeat index 5

Comment: That’s why there’s the drop duplicate at the end. See the actual result. @anon01

Comment: ah yeah, it's just not reassigned to new_df

Answer (score 0):

```
filter = df.loc[df['label'] == -1].index

req_idx = []
for idx in filter:
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    elif idx == 1:
        req_idx.append(idx-1)
    else:
        req_idx.append(idx-2)
        req_idx.append(idx-1)

req_idx = list(set(req_idx))


df2 = df.loc[df.index.isin(req_idx)]

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   val  label
1  2.4      2
2 -2.3      1
4  3.2      1
5  2.4      2
6 -2.3     -1
8  2.4      1
9 -2.3      1
```

This should also work if you have the label as -1 in the first two rows